# appc-security-server will be available soon

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

All of a sudden while opening my dashboard on Titanium Studio I am getting following error:

503 Service Unavailable.
No server is available to handle this request.

I searched on Google for the error but found nothing except for the same question asked at Appcelerator Forum as this [link](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/183084/appc-security-server-will-be-available-soon-ergent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got resolved itself I guess it was due to some error from Appcelerator services or their server was down.

Comment: Yep, sorry for that Rahul.